# PowerShell Mirror newer File into another

Tags: powershell, directory, copy, powershell-3.0, mirror

I need some help with PowerShell, I tried for hours but I couldn't figure out how that works. (The Text in the code is German, just ignore that) For the Program I basically wanted to do that when you mirror the files, that the newer file in each folder gets mirrored. So for example I have 2 folders: temp and temp2. There's a file in temp example.txt created at 12:00 PM and there's a file in temp2 with the same name created at 2:00PM. I want to mirror the newer file, even if it is in the destination folder, i want to mirror it into the source folder if the file in the destination folder is newer.

I hope that this explanation is kinda understandable, and that someone can help with that. I tried to figure it out myself but I didn't make it. I'd be really happy for an answer

```
write-host "Bitte geben Sie den Sourcepath ein, nur Ordner. Am ende des zielordners Ordners KEIN backslash"
$source = Read-Host
write-host "Bitte geben Sie den Destinationpath ein. Am ende des zielordners Ordners KEIN backslash"
$destination = Read-Host
while($True){
    write-host "Wollen sie irgendwelche Dateiendungen NICHT rüber kopieren? j=ja, n=nein"
    $choice0 = read-host
    if($choice0 -eq "j"){
        write-host "Welche dateiendung?"
        $fileendInput = read-host
        $fileending = "*." + $fileendInput
        break
    }
    elseif($choice0 -eq "n"){
        break
    }
    else{
        write-host "Ungültige eingabe, nochmal probieren."
    }
}

$Exclude = @($fileending)

Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse | ForEach {
    $ModifiedDestination = $($_.FullName).Replace("$source","$destination")
    If ((Test-Path $ModifiedDestination) -eq $False) {
        Copy-Item $_.FullName $ModifiedDestination -Exclude $Exclude
        }
 }

 Remove-Variable fileendInput
 Remove-Variable fileending 
 Remove-Variable Exclude
```

Comment: By mirror you mean you want to replace the file with newer version?

Comment: I want to replace the older file with the newer file, that's what I mean

Comment: While PowerShell is a great tool for many purposes, I'm having a hard time figuring out how a person could ever make it do what some free products out there can do when it comes to copying files.  The two tools I currently like the most is https://fastcopy.jp/ and https://freefilesync.org/.  Both have GUI. FreeFileSync has a xml based Batch script executable from other scripts. FastCopy is one of the fastest programs out there and fairly reasonable command line parameters.  Both do have a learning curve, but not steep when compared to properly copying files in PowerShell.